# XSL FO: <FO:inline-container> overflowing table content

Tags: java, xsl-fo, apache-xml-graphics

I have a fo:table inside fo:inline-contaner. My question is ,How to place overflowing table below in the page or in the next page.
I am using apache xmlgraphics 2.7
Here is a short code extract:

```
                    <fo:block line-stacking-strategy="max-height">

                        <xsl:for-each select="./somelist">
                            <fo:inline-container>
                            <xsl:text>&#8203;</xsl:text>
                            <fo:table width="100%" border="1pt solid black">
                                <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
                                <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
                                <fo:table-header>
                                    <fo:table-row background-color="lightgrey">
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block font-weight="bold">Header 1</fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block font-weight="bold">Header 2</fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </fo:table-header>
                                <fo:table-body>
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block>Row 1, Cell 1</fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block>Row 1, Cell 2</fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block>Row 2, Cell 1</fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block>Row 2, Cell 2</fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </fo:table-body>
                            </fo:table>
                            </fo:inline-container>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:block>
```

And output of above code is:
[image]

Current Behaviour:
[image]

expected behaviour:

[image]

Comment: Maybe try to insert a Zero-width_space character between `<fo:inline-container>`
Something like `<xsl:text>&#8203;</xsl:text>` See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space

Comment: Did you try adding `line-stacking-strategy="max-height"` to the parent `fo:block` like suggested in the [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78074749/317052)?

Comment: Did you try the two suggestions?

Comment: yes, I have tried both solutions but none of them is working

Comment: PS. I have edited the code snippet according to your suggestions. Please point out if I have done it in the wrong way.

Comment: I would put `<xsl:text>&#8203;</xsl:text>` as first element of `<xsl:for-each select="./somelist">`

Comment: yes after putting <xsl:text>&#8203;</xsl:text> as the first element of <xsl:for-each select="./somelist">, tables are placed below one another not next to each other. Please recommend suggestion based on my expected behaviour.

Comment: Here table2,table 3 are placed below table 1. I want table 1 and 2 in one block(div) and table 3 placed below that block(div).